# ionic 3 app with both side menu and tabs

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I followed this tutorial to create an ionic 3 app with both side menu and tabs [link](https://competenepal.com/ion-sidemenu-with-tabs/)

Everything works fine in the beginning, this is my app: [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhauR.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5N97.png)

This is the code of my app.component.ts:

```
export interface PageInterface {
  title: string;
  name: string;
  component: any;
  icon: string;
  index?: number;
  tabName?: string;
  tabComponent?: any;
}

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage: any = TabsPage;
  pages: PageInterface[] = [
    { title: 'Home', name: 'HomePage', component: HomePage, tabComponent: HomePage, index: 0, icon: 'home' },
    { title: 'Demandes', name: 'DemandesPage', component: DemandesPage, tabComponent: DemandesPage, index: 1, icon: 'body' },
    { title: 'Ajouter un trajet', name: 'AddTraject', component: AddtrajectPage, tabComponent:AddtrajectPage, index: 2, icon: 'create' },
    { title: 'Ajouter une demande', name: 'AddDemande', component: AdddemandePage, tabComponent:AdddemandePage, index: 3, icon: 'add' },
    { title: 'About', name: 'AboutPage', component: AboutPage, tabComponent: AboutPage,  icon: 'people' },
    { title: 'Contact', name: 'ContactPage', component: ContactPage, tabComponent: ContactPage,  icon: 'contacts' },
    { title: 'Special', name: 'SpecialPage', component: OtherPage, icon: 'shuffle' },
  ];

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page: PageInterface) {
    let params = {};

    // The index is equal to the order of our tabs inside tabs.ts
    if (page.index) {
      params = { tabIndex: page.index };
    }

   // If tabs page is already active just change the tab index
    if (this.nav.getActiveChildNavs().length && page.index != undefined) {
      this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0].select(page.index);
    } else {
      // Tabs are not active, so reset the root page 
      // In this case: moving to or from SpecialPage
      this.nav.setRoot(page.component, params);
    }


  }

  isActive(page: PageInterface) {
    // Again the Tabs Navigation
    let childNav = this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0];

    if (childNav) {
      if (childNav.getSelected() && childNav.getSelected().root === page.tabComponent) {
        return 'primary';
      }
      return;
    }

    // Fallback needed when there is no active childnav (tabs not active)
    if (this.nav.getActive() && this.nav.getActive().name === page.name) {
      return 'primary';
    }
    return;
  }

}
```

and i have only four pages in the tab,

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Trajets" tabIcon="car"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Demandes" tabIcon="body"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="+ trajet" tabIcon="create"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="+ demande" tabIcon="add"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

the problem is when I click for example on contact, which is in the side menu and not in the tabs, i get the contact page but without tab. 
I want to know how can i include the tab in all pages . Please help guys.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a little bit of work.

Your ionic app has one `nav` variable which is global and is one that you use for the side menu. This variable is the `nav` inside app.component.ts.

Also, each tab has its own `NavController`. What you want is to push the page that is clicked on the left side menu on the local `NavController` of the active tab, rather than the global `nav`.

One way to do this, is to store the `navCtrl` of each tab in a global variable in its constructor:

```
constructor(navParams: NavParams, navCtrl : navCtrl) {
    this.tabNumber= //number of this tab;
    // Set the active tab based on the passed index from menu.ts
    Globals.navCtrls[this.tabNumber] = this.navCtrl;
  }
```

Now inside `app.component.ts`, instead of setRoot, you should have something like:

```
 Globals.navCtrls[**number of active tab**].push(page.component, params);
```

**How to define a global variable?**

Create a new file: `config.ts` which has this:

```
export var Globals = {
  //Nav ctrl of each tab page
   navCtrls : new Array( **Number of tab pages**),
}
```

Then in each file:

```
import { Globals } from "path/to/config.ts";
```

**Easy but not perfect alternative**:

I see that you use setRoot to show a new page. Rather than this, you could use `push`:

```
this.nav.setRoot(page.component, params);
```

You still won't see the tabs, but at least you will be able to go back to the previous page.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'll try this asap and get back to you.